# jquery UI DatePicker. ARIA integration

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am working on a jquery UI Datepicker and I need an ARIA Integration. 
The datepicker doesn't read out loud when you try to read it with JAWS, when i type aria-label="THE DATE" it will read the date out and it works.

My question, how do i transform the standard jquery UI DatePicker so that it will say aria-label="and then the date"

Thanks !!

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a basic example, you could try something like:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, dateObject) {
      var myDT = $.datepicker.parseDate($(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"), dateText);
      var ariaDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD, MM d, yy", myDT);
      console.log("Date added to ARIA label: " + ariaDate);
      $(this).attr("aria-label", ariaDate);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" aria-label="No date selected"></p>
```

Assuming you want the `aria-label` in a more Human format, I converted the string from the selection back to a Date object. I can then format it back to a String. It's a little bit of back and forth, yet it will then be understandable by the reader.

Example from console: `Date added to ARIA label: Wednesday, February 28, 2018`
The resulting HTML looks like:

```
<input id="datepicker" aria-label="Wednesday, February 28, 2018" class="hasDatepicker" type="text">
```

Hope that helps.

References:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks!!
I actually made the function work, but when my code review came back, the question was to make it simpler. and this is the code to make it simpler then the code that i wrote!
Thank you very much